# C# Serial Port Hangs after received data

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
    public void ClosePort()
    {
        if (comPort.IsOpen == true)
        {
            Thread CloseDown = new Thread(() => CloseSerialOnExit(comPort)); //close port in new thread to avoid hang

            CloseDown.Start(); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
        }
    }

    private void CloseSerialOnExit(SerialPort port)
    {
        port.DiscardOutBuffer();
        port.Close();

        DisplayData(MessageType.Error, "Port communication has been closed" + " " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
    }
```

why when my app received data close is not work?. is it another solution for this case? my work step is :

1. Connect port,
2. Scan and received data,
3. Disconnect port, and repeat start from connect port again, but when we want to start connect port, system show error message :

> access com port is denied.

i thing that happen because the port is not actually close. how to close the port?

this is my code in open port

```
public bool OpenPort()
    {
        try
        {
            //first check if the port is already open
            //if its open then close it
            if (comPort.IsOpen == true) comPort.Close();

            //set the properties of our SerialPort Object
            comPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(_baudRate);    //BaudRate
            comPort.DataBits = int.Parse(_dataBits);    //DataBits
            comPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), _stopBits);    //StopBits
            comPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), _parity);    //Parity
            comPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), _parity);    //Parity                
            comPort.PortName = _portName;   //PortName
            //now open the port
            comPort.WriteTimeout = 400;//Write timeout, if the efficiency of the serial driver software, can effectively avoid the deadlock
            comPort.ReadTimeout = 400;//Read timeout, ibid
            comPort.Open();
            comPort.DtrEnable = false;
            comPort.RtsEnable = false;
            //display message
            DisplayData(MessageType.Normal, "Port opened at " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
            //return true
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayData(MessageType.Error, ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is my code in comPort_datareceived

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            //determine the mode the user selected (binary/string)
            switch (CurrentTransmissionType)
            {
                //user chose string
                case TransmissionType.Text:
                    //read data waiting in the buffer
                    string msg = comPort.ReadExisting();
                    //display the data to the user
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, msg + "\n");
                    break;
                //user chose binary
                case TransmissionType.Hex:
                    //retrieve number of bytes in the buffer
                    int OpeCode = 0;
                    int RequestID = 0;
                    int Product = 0;
                    int IPenNo = 0;
                    string status = " ";

                    while (true)
                    {
                        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             // Use current time.
                        string format = "dddddddd, MMMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                        string currentTime = time.ToString(format);
                        byte[] TrueData = new byte[256];

                        try
                        {
                            int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
                            if (bytes == 0) continue;
                            //create a byte array to hold the awaiting data
                            byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
                            comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Hexa :" + ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "\n");
                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Byte :" + bytes.ToString() + "\n");

                            if (bytes == 3)
                            {
                                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath).ToList();

                                // Remove as many lines as you'd like from the end
                                if (lines.Count > 2)
                                {
                                    lines.RemoveRange(lines.Count - 2, 2);
                                }

                                // Iterate backwards through the list until we've updated 2 (or more or less) lines
                                var linesUpdated = 0;

                                for (var i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0 && linesUpdated < 1; i--)
                                {
                                    if (lines[i].Contains("OK"))
                                    {
                                        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("OK", "NG");
                                        linesUpdated++;
                                    }
                                }

                                File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.ToArray());
                                //DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "NG" + "\n");
                            }

                            if (bytes == 2)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            int etx_ok = 0;

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                            {
                                if (comBuffer[i] == 0x02)
                                {
                                    //DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "cek II:" + checkStatus + "\n");
                                    int length = comBuffer[i + 1];
                                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Length=" + length.ToString() + "\n");

                                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bytes.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        status = "NG";
                                    }
                                    if (length + i + 1 != bytes && status == " ")
                                    {
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, length.ToString() + " " + i.ToString() + " " + bytes.ToString() + " ");
                                        status = "NG";
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ERROR \n");
                                        //break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        status = "OK";
                                    }

                                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ini statusnya  : " + status + "\n");

                                    if (comBuffer[length + i - 1] == 0x03)
                                    {
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ETX OK\n");
                                        etx_ok = 1;
                                        OpeCode = comBuffer[i + 2];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "OpeCode=" + OpeCode.ToString() + ",");
                                        RequestID = comBuffer[i + 3];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "RequestID=" + RequestID.ToString() + ",");
                                        int StoreCode = comBuffer[i + 4];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "StoreCode=" + StoreCode.ToString() + ",");
                                        int ProductBatteryTraining = comBuffer[i + 5];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ProductBatteryTraining=" + ProductBatteryTraining.ToString() + ",");

                                        Product = ProductBatteryTraining >> 4;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Product=" + Product.ToString() + ",");
                                        int Battery = ProductBatteryTraining & 4;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Batery=" + Battery.ToString() + ",");
                                        int Training = ProductBatteryTraining & 1;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Training=" + Training.ToString() + ",");

                                        IPenNo = comBuffer[i + 6];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "IPenNo=" + IPenNo.ToString() + ",");

                                        int CrcCalc = comBuffer[length + i] + 0x11;

                                        for (int j = 7, k = 0; j < length; j++, k++)
                                        {
                                            //syswrite STDOUT , "TrueDataX " . $length . "\n";
                                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "TrueDataX " + length.ToString() + "," + "\n");
                                            TrueData[k] = comBuffer[i + j];
                                        }
                                        if (OpeCode == 0x63)
                                        {
                                            byte[] replyStr = new byte[] { 
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x45), Convert.ToByte(0x53), Convert.ToByte(0x4c), Convert.ToByte(0x14), Convert.ToByte(0x09), Convert.ToByte(0x00),                             //#Length Change
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x02), Convert.ToByte(0x08),Convert.ToByte(OpeCode), Convert.ToByte(RequestID),Convert.ToByte(Product-1), Convert.ToByte(IPenNo),                                       //#Reply Header Data                   
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x00),                                                                                                                                           //#Reply Status      
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x03), Convert.ToByte(CrcCalc),                                                                                                                     //#Footer Data    
                                        Convert.ToByte(0xcc), Convert.ToByte(0xcc) 
                                        };

                                            comPort.Write(replyStr, 0, replyStr.Length);

                                            //write file to textfile
                                            //string path = @"d:\yosafat\testfile\tes1_Friday0916201614.33.txt"; 
                                            string IPenID = IPenNo.ToString();
                                            string appendText = ("IPen ID \t" + "Datetime\t\t\t\t\t" + "Status" + Environment.NewLine + IPenID + "\t\t" + currentTime + "\t\t" + status + Environment.NewLine);
                                            File.AppendAllText(Fullpath, appendText);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        OpeCode = 0;
                                        //syswrite STDOUT , "ETX Bad Data" . $length . "\n";
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ETX Bad Data" + length.ToString() + "\n");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (etx_ok == 1)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
            }
        }
    public static int GetFirstOccurance(byte byteToFind, byte[] byteArray)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(byteArray, byteToFind);
    }
```

Comment: How long was the interval between `Close` and `Open`? Why do you need to repeat open/close? I thing it's better to keep the port open.

Comment: @IPutuSusila yes i must close the port because the received data will saved to textfile and when hit the button disconnect will end scan and received data.

Comment: Of course you need to close when requested, i.e. through disconnect button. So, you means that after you hit the disconnect button, then when you hit connect, the error was raised? Can you show us the code which connect/open the serial port?

Comment: It's quite difficult to troubleshoot without additional information on how you read the data (sync or async?, single/multithread?, did you use timeout?). I'm using `SerialPort` to acquire data continuously from several instruments without any problem. Probably you can listen to `SerialPort.Disposed` event to make sure the port is closed/disposed before trying to reopen it again.

Comment: yes that error was raised if i disconnect and connect again, thats my code open serial port please see my new edit post, i add the comPort datareceived too that code is handling the data received.

Comment: are you indonesian? i look in your name, your name like a bali's people

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123916/discussion-between-i-putu-susila-and-yosafat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` inside `catch` block in `SerialPort.DataReceived` event handler to quit from `while` loop in case `exception` occurred.

```
while (true)
{
    //...
    try {
        //...
    } catch (Exception) { return; //add this}
}
```

After the other thread `Close` the port, `Exception` may occurs when reading data (this line: `comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);`). Without `return` statement, you will never quit `while` loop and GC won't dispose **SerialPort**. Thus, when you try to re-open the port, you will failed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call `CloseSerialOnExit` in a separate thread? Wouldn't it be easier to call it synchronously? Does it really take to much time?

Anyway, if you need it to be like that, you should make sure that the `Thread` object is not GC'ed before the thread is finished. You should make the `CloseDown` a member.

You could also use some synchronization to see if the `ClosePort` has finished at the beginning of `OpenPort`.

```
Thread CloseDown = null;
public void ClosePort()
{
    if (comPort.IsOpen == true)
    {
        CloseDown = new Thread(() => CloseSerialOnExit(comPort)); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
        CloseDown.Start(); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
    }
}
```